# Android - Динамическое изменение размера текста.

Tags: android-textview, android, java

Здравствуйте! Есть TextView, который занимает весь экран. Как можно подогать размер текста, чтобы он занимал весь экран, *не* создавая кастомный TextView?

Размер строки всегда одинаков: моноширинный шрифт, 1 строка и 8 символов.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, возможно, вам поможет [это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485887/191718)