# Динамическое масштабирование текста в TextView android

Tags: android, android-layout

Задача:  в списке элемента сделать фиксироваными отступы сверху, снизу и между строками. Я задал отступы в корневом элементе, если задать эти отступы в LinearLayout котором находятся TextView, то текст тоже не масштабируется, а нижние и верхние края залазят  на текст и перекрывают его. Как сделать так что бы размер шрифта менялся? При этом высота элемента списка должна быть фиксированной.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="97.5dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:layout_paddingTop="20dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
>


<!-- Progress Bar -->

<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    custom:donut_progress="70"
    custom:donut_text_size="10sp"
    custom:donut_text_color="@color/colorBlack"
    custom:donut_finished_color="@color/colorGreen"
    custom:donut_unfinished_color="@color/colorBackgroundDarckGrey"
    custom:donut_finished_stroke_width="4.5dp"
    custom:donut_unfinished_stroke_width="4.5dp"
    />

<!-- Title of package-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/titleDescriptionCase"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buyCase"

    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Rihanna Love the way"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontBlue"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Just gona stand there and ..."
        android:textColor="#535353"
        android:textSize="13sp"

        />

</LinearLayout>


<!--Buy and about-->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buyCase"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/titleDescriptionCase">

    <!-- Buy button -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBuy"
        android:layout_width="62.5dp"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_board_baground"
        android:text="4.99 $"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontBlue"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />

    <!-- Short description about package -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:text="230 words"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<!--  SHADOWS -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/shadowLayoutBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2.5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1.7dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_top"
    android:orientation="vertical" />




 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: крутой интерфейс

Comment: @dDevil в смысле?

Comment: ну, красивый:) или тут такое не принято?

Comment: @dDevil пардон, мне на секунду показалось, что это был сарказм!

Comment: Стоит заметить, что список с разным размером шрифтов в айтемах выглядит просто отвратительно. Вы сами это увидите, когда потратите время на реализацию очередного "костыля".

Comment: @pavlofff да, я понимаю, просто количество символов в TextView  может измениться, и я думал что можно как то динамически подстроится под это!

Comment: Укажите размер, который будет подходит для самой большой надписи для всех айтемов (или свойство `android:ellipsize` для обрезки концов строк, которые не входят).Так же стоит заметить, что по гайдлайнам гугла - [ячейка базовой сетки для виджетов](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html) равна 8dp. **ВОСЕМЬ DP!!!**. Это больше того, что указываете вы в 40 РАЗ!! Вы же понимаете, что 1.7dp никто без лупы не отличит от 2 dp. И Нет в верстке никаких таких размеров - 62.5dp. Минимальная кратность - 4dp, да и то мелковато.

Comment: Скажите, вы тестировали свою разметку на реальном устройстве (не в визуальном редакторе IDE или эмуляторе на компьютере) ? Размер 26dp - это **3.6 миллиметра**  на экране реального смартфона. Думаете пользователю понравиться целиться в эту полоску ..

Comment: @pavlofff данную разметку только на эмуляторе 720х1280 320dpi

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо, ознакомлюсь. Из реальных устройств, пока что только Nexus 7 ( тот что нестандартный ). Что из смартфоном может быть оптимальным вариантом? подумываю о Nexus 4 или 5 ?

Comment: В общем приблизительно : 160dp = примерно 4in (дюйма) = примерно 25 мм (плюс минус пара миллиметров для разных экранов). Тестируйте на реальном устройстве, иначе потом возможна боль от неожиданности :) . 8dp соответствует примерно 1 мм, поэтому он принят за шаг базовой сетки. [Почитайте перевод гугловской инструкции](http://pr0andr0id.blogspot.ru/2014/02/blog-post_20.html) по дизайну интерфейсов, он должен вам помочь .

Comment: Для кнопок размер меньше 32dp (размер кнопки в ActionBar) уже издевательство над пользователем. В нее трудно попасть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview подходящая для этой задачи либа, наглядный пример по ссылке

Comment: а без либы просто версткой этот вопрос не решается?

Comment: ах, если б это решалось версткой, либы бы не было :) Может когда-нибудь верстка в Android будет такой же приятной как в CSS, но нет

Comment: ясно, вас понял)